# Is it possible to make a wxDataViewCtrl auto scroll to the bottom?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxDataViewCtrl to display a list of items, when I add an item to the control, is it possible to make wxDataViewCtrl auto scroll to the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not automatically but you just need to call [wxDataViewCtrl::EnsureVisible()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html#a892b67293dfc764d053fd764266c4326) to do it.